# Interpretation question: Textstat_similarity Quanteda

Tags: r, text, cosine-similarity, quanteda, sentence-similarity

I have a dataset of 310,225 tweets. I want to find out how many tweets were same or similar. I calculated the similarity between the tweets using Quanteda's textstat frequency. I found that the frequency of distance 1 and 0.9999 in the similarity matrix as below:

```
0.9999            1 
 2288           162743
```

Here's my code:

```
dfmat_users <- dfm_data %>% 
dfm_select(min_nchar = 2) %>% 
dfm_trim(min_termfreq = 10) 

dfmat_users <- dfmat_users[ntoken(dfmat_users) > 10,]

tstat_sim <- textstat_simil(dfmat_users, method = "cosine", margin = "documents", min_simil = 0.9998)

table(tstat_sim@x) #result of this code is given above.
```

I need to find out the number of similar or same tweets in the dataset. How should I interpret the results above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to convert the `textstat_simil()` output to a data.frame of unique pairs, and then filter the ones whose cosine value is above your threshold (here, .9999).

To illustrate, we can reshape the built-in inaugural address corpus into sentences, and then compute the similarity matrix on these, and then do the coercion to data.frame and use **dplyr** to filter the results you want.

```r
library("quanteda", warn.conflicts = FALSE)
## Package version: 2.1.0.9000
## Parallel computing: 2 of 8 threads used.
## See https://quanteda.io for tutorials and examples.

sim_df <- data_corpus_inaugural %>%
  corpus_reshape(to = "sentences") %>%
  dfm() %>%
  textstat_simil(method = "cosine") %>%
  as.data.frame()

nrow(sim_df)
## [1] 12508670
```

You can adjust the condition below for your data to 0.9999 - here I'm using 0.99 as an illustration.

```r
library("dplyr", warn.conflicts = FALSE)
filter(sim_df, cosine > .99)
##            document1       document2 cosine
## 1    1861-Lincoln.69 1861-Lincoln.71      1
## 2    1861-Lincoln.69 1861-Lincoln.73      1
## 3    1861-Lincoln.71 1861-Lincoln.73      1
## 4  1953-Eisenhower.6   1985-Reagan.6      1
## 5  1953-Eisenhower.6    1989-Bush.15      1
## 6      1985-Reagan.6    1989-Bush.15      1
## 7      1989-Bush.140  2009-Obama.108      1
## 8      1989-Bush.140   2013-Obama.87      1
## 9     2009-Obama.108   2013-Obama.87      1
## 10     1989-Bush.140    2017-Trump.9      1
## 11    2009-Obama.108    2017-Trump.9      1
## 12     2013-Obama.87    2017-Trump.9      1
```

(And: yeah, that's a very fast computation of cosine similarity between 12.5 million sentence pairs!)